# How to set array on view from database? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to pass a string from my database to my view. In my model I've put this:

```
public function getSeries($limit = 10, $order = 'id_s', $das = 'desc')
    {
        $this->db->select('*')
                 ->from('s_series')
                 ->where(array('nom_s' => $nom_s))
                 ->order_by($order, $das)
                 ->limit($limit);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

In my controller

```
$data['lastSeries'] = $this->series->getSeries();
```

In my view

```
<? foreach($lastSeries as $lserie): ?>
                            <li>
                            <article class="pli-lg">
    <header>
        <figure><a href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/hakuouki-movie-2-shikon-soukyuu.html">
        <img src="https://todoanimes.com/img/animes/portadas_260x310/hakuouki-movie-2-shikon-soukyuu.jpg" alt="Hakuouki Movie 2: Shikon Soukyuu"><span class="iconb-ver"></span></a></figure>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2><a href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/hakuouki-movie-2-shikon-soukyuu.html"><? echo $lserie['nom_s']; ?></a></h2>
        <a class="botn-smll" href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/hakuouki-movie-2-shikon-soukyuu.html">PELICULA</a>
    </section>
</article>  

<article class="pli-sm">
    <header>
        <figure><a href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/taifuu-no-noruda.html">
        <img src="https://todoanimes.com/img/animes/portadas_50x70/taifuu-no-noruda.jpg" alt="Taifuu no Noruda"><span class="iconb-ver"></span></a></figure>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2><a href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/taifuu-no-noruda.html">Taifuu no Noruda</a></h2>
        <a class="botn-smll" href="http://todoanimes.com/pelicula/taifuu-no-noruda.html">PELICULA</a>
    </section>  
</article>

                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But when I want to view in my view it show this message:

[image]

Somebody know, what is the problem?

I've deleted this line from my code:

```
->where(array('nom_s' => $nom_s))
```

but now in my source code show this:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Illegal string offset 'nom_s'</p>
<p>Filename: pages/home.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 41</p>
    <p>Backtrace:</p>
            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\pages\home.php<br />
            Line: 41<br />
            Function: _error_handler            </p>

            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\Pages.php<br />
            Line: 25<br />
            Function: view          </p>

            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>
```

the string nom_s is a field of my table s_series

Comment: show your entire controller method

Comment: How you getting `$nom_s` in your model?

Comment: when I call my table from my db 
$this->db->select('*')
      ->from('s_series')
      ->where(array('nom_s' => $nom_s))
      ->order_by($order, $das)
      ->limit($limit);
   $query = $this->db->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your Last Line

return $query->result_array();

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot. I've solved my problem with your help

Answer (score 0):

Please check your query first, is your query right or wrong.

Try this:

```
$data['lastSeries'] = $this->series->getSeries();

echo $this->db->last_query();
```